# JSON deserialize only with at least 2 parameters

Tags: java, cxf, jax-rs, apache-tomee, jettison

I'm implementing a RESTful service application for **TomEE Plus 1.7.1** with **Jettison** as default json provider. I have several facade classes for my entitiy classes to provide CRUD functionalities for each of them. Service facades have been generated by netbeans.

This is the POST method:

```
@POST
public void create(Course entity) {
    super.create(entity);
}
```

While using this method (to create a new instance in the database) I got following error:

```
No message body reader has been found for request class Object, ContentType : application/json.
```

After several hours of trying, I got it to work: I only had to add another parameter to the method, like that:

```
@POST
public void create(@Context Context uriInfo, Course entity) {
    super.create(entity);
}
```

I don't understand why I had to add this Context parameter. I don't need the context variable, so actually I would like to remove it...

Does anybody know the reason?

Comment: I have used `Jackson provider` and there you do not need `@Context`. I suspect this could be `Jettison` specific. Not sure though..

Comment: I tried that as well, but unfortunately got another error then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I found the solution:

All my rest services have been implemented as facade classes. The abstract facade (super class of all services) has several methods like:

```
public void create(T entity) { getEntityManager().persist(entity); }
public void edit(T entity) {getEntityManager().merge(entity);}
```

These methods are used by the facade classes:

```
public void create(Course entity) {
    super.create(entity);
}

public void edit(@PathParam("id") Integer id, Course entity) {
    super.edit(entity);
}
```

(for better viewing I've removed the annotations here)

The difference between these two methods is, that the edit method has a second parameter "id" and so does not override the edit() method of the super class. But the create() method does only have a single parameter which causes override of the super class method "create()". I don't know why, but cxf is now creating two endpoints:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/webprog/api/course/  ->      void create(Course)           

POST http://localhost:8080/webprog/api/course/  ->      void create(Object)
```

This is also the reason why I got it working with a secon parameter: The create() method is not getting overriden anymore.

So what i did now, is simply renaming the method in de super class, to not override them in the facade classes.

**by the way: all services classes have been created by netbeans generator... maybe there is a bug in it**

Comment: 0_o Now that you mention it, the create method is the *only* method which has @Override (except for findAll).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the pointers

1. Make sure you have jettison jar in your classpath, CXF automatically registers jettison as json provider.
2. `@Context` Context is not mandatory, so if you want to access some context parameters you can add.
3. For Method create add Media Type `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`
4. Finally Check why you are getting `No message body reader has been found for request class Object` Ideally you should have got `No message body reader has been found for request class Course`(There might be some issues with your class definations)

Comment: Thanks four your answer!

1.) Jettison is in the classpath as it is the default json provider (serialization is working well)
2.) I know that it is not mandatory, but bizarrely it is only working, if i put it as parameter
3.) MediaType has already been added 
4.) I think, that my class defitinion is okay, i used all the important annotations and, as I said before, serialization in get-method is working well

Comment: Its worth seeing your configuration file, the cxf one

Comment: I don't habe such cxf confguration, because it is embedded in TomEE and comes with its own one. But I did override some of the default values by following: dropRootElement=true; supportUnwrapped = true;       dropCollectionWrapperElement=true; serializeAsArray=true. that is working properly when transforming objects to json...